# Get a list of my previous checkins using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I understand with the new Graph api v2, starting from 30th of April 2015, it is not possible to get my friend's checkins for privacy reasons. But is it possible to get a list of "my" previous checkins using graph api?

I tried **me?fields=checkins**

but it returns

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#12) checkins API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 12
  }
}
```

I don't know any other ways to retrieve this data.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In V2.4 you can retrieve data by using this.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=tagged.with(<friends>)
```

you can check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Replace `me?fields=id,name` with `me?fields=tagged.with(<friends>)`